# How can I tell the time with an Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

I'd like to tell the time with my Apple TV, so I don't have to use a computer. But I can't seem to find a single clock app or screensaver for Apple TV. Anyone know if one exists?

I'm using an Apple TV 3, with Apple TV Software 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the shameless plug, but I made the app just because Apple TV lacks the time: [Screen Clock](https://www.producthunt.com/tech/screenclock).

Answer (score 1):

On the Apple TV models with apps and Siri ([4th & 5th generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV#4th_and_5th_generation))…

## Ask Siri

Simply ask Siri for the current time. Hold down the remote button to speak with Siri.

## Progress bar

While watching a video in play, tap the touch surface once to see the time remaining to elapse to the end of that show/movie/clip.

[image]

Tap again the touch surface to alter the markers on the play **progress bar to current time-of-day** and estimated time when that show will be done playing if uninterrupted.

[image]

Comment: The second part of your answer doesn't seem to match the question.

Comment: @patrix The Question asks to tell time. I showed how a second tap of touch surface shows the current time as you watch a show. Where is the mismatch?

Comment: I doubt that the OP wants to start a video just to be able to see the time :-) But ok, while watching one it might be helpful.